# SIlverlight/XNA split application drawing differently in WP7 and WP8

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

I built a game for WP7 that used the combination of both Silverlight and XNA in the same page. The page contained 3 separate Silverlight controls which appeared in the GamePage.xaml page

```
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBox Name="box2" Height="74" Margin="0,0,132,8" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <TextBox Name="box1" Margin="0,480,8,82" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="  send  " Margin="0,0,20,8" Click ="sendMessage_Click" Grid.Row="1" Height="74" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

On WP7 the 3 Silverlight controls drew correctly using this C# code in GamePage.xaml.cs

```
UIElementRenderer elementRenderer;

void GamePage_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActualHeight > 0 && ActualWidth > 0 && elementRenderer == null)
        {
            elementRenderer = new UIElementRenderer(this, (int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight);
        }
    }

private void OnDraw(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
    {
        SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        elementRenderer.Render();

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(elementRenderer.Texture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

In WP8 all 3 Silverlight controls are usable by pressing where they should appear, however only box1 is drawn and there is empty transparent space where the other controls should be.

Any help greatly appreciated, I know this could prove to be a difficult problem to solve.